# How can I get IntelliJ's Find in Files to always open in "In Project" mode?

Tags: intellij-idea

As a long-time Visual Studio user, I often use Find in Files to find things throughout the project.

In IntelliJ, this is causing me problems, because sometimes IntelliJ decides, for some reason, that what I want is "Directory" rather than "In Project".  (I usually notice this after I'm baffled by the small number of matches.)

How can I get IntelliJ to exclusively open Find in Files in In Project mode, and never in one of the other settings?

[image: Find in Files set to Directory instead of In Project]

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to invoke *Find in Files* action with *In Project* scope instead of *Directory* permanently. *Find in Files* switches to *Directory* automatically if you are focusing in the *Project* tool window (*View | Tool Windows | Project*). Otherwise, it opens in the previous state.

You can see and follow [IDEA-270151](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-270151) to change the current behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I've added my own comments there.